# Kill running instance of an azure function using Invocation Id

Tags: azure, azure-functions

How can I kill running instance of an azure function  using InvocationId if I have it stored in my database?

Answer (score 1):

I doubt if there is a way to kill specific instance as of now. However you can stop the function app itself.

Here is a similar [**ask**](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/issues/1130) which you can refer.